# Django error while creating superuser, AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py, manage.py

I am using Django version 1.11.3 and djangorestframework version 3.6.3. At the stage of creating the superuser with the following command:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

This command was supposed to ask me about my Email and Password, though it does ask me the Email but after entering my Email, I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/shivams334/myapp2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/shivams334/myapp2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/shivams334/myapp2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/shivams334/myapp2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 63, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/shivams334/myapp2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/shivams334/myapp2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 121, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).get_by_natural_key(username)
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'
```

My models.py is this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

class UserProfileManager(object):
    """helps django work with our custom user model"""
    def create_user(self,email,name,password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have email')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user
    def create_superuser(self,email,name,password):
        """creates and saves a new superuser with given details"""
        user = self.create_user(email,name,password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)   

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    """docstring for UserProfile"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        """used to get a user full name"""
        return self.name

    def get_short_name():
        """used to get a users short name"""
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        """Django uses this when it needs to convert the object into string"""
        return self.email
```

And I also updated the Application Definition in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'profiles_api',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'profiles_api.UserProfile'
```

I have tried to do this with both python2 and python3 but the error is same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UserProfileManager` should be inherited from `BaseUserManager` class, not from `object`:

```
class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
...
```

You can find example of implementation custom user model [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)